# Commons Digester: How to build complex, XML-based queries with Apache Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, apache-commons-digester

I need to build a XML-based query with Apache Lucene and Commons Digester.

My docs have this format:

```
<doc>
<id>361492799</id>
<title>Dan1</title>
<description>We had another Flickr meetup in Rochester, the biggest that Ive been to. 12 people showed up.Da, he was to the right.</description>
<time>18934934</time>
<tags>flickrmeetup rochester dan totheright 200701</tags>
<geo><latitude>324234</latitude><longitude>28342349</longitude></geo>
<event>135961</event>
</doc>
```

And the query is actually also a document that I need to compare with the entire collection. Each attribute has a different similarity metric.  For example, "description" has tf-idf cosine similarity. "Time" is just the difference and "latitude" + "longitude" is compared using the haversine distance.

For now I've only performed searches with simple textual queries such as "word1 word2". How can I build more complex queries instead ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to build a XML-based query with
>   Apache Lucene and Commons Digester.

This [**article**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-lucene/) should help you get started

for analysing content from xml, take a look at [TIKA](http://tika.apache.org/)

> Apache Tika - a content analysis
>   toolkit
>
> Apache Tika™ is a toolkit for
>   detecting and extracting metadata and
>   structured text content from various
>   documents using existing parser
>   libraries.

Comment: THanks, i've solved the first part of my problem, which is the parsing of the data. I now need to build a query having the same (XML) structure of the docs. You know how can I do this ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at SOLR? SOLR is basically Lucene+an entire XML based querying and indexing server.

Comment: I actually don't need anymore a parser but to build a query with the same XML structure of the collection documents